# How to optimise Collatz sequence in python sequence?

Tags: python, math, logic, collatz

The Collatz sequence rules are as follows:

- If n = odd: n = 3n + 1
- If n = even: n = n/2

I am a student with a basic level of python and need to minimise the number of numbers I check to find the longest sequence less than 100. I need to output the starting term of said sequence. Both even numbers and multiples of five can be the answer (if you are looking at answers less than 20 the answer is 18) and am unsure what to check).

Code below works but checks 100 numbers:

```
highest = 0
highest_num = 0




def Collatz(num, highest, highest_num):
    iterations = 0
    
    while num!=1:
        
        if num%2 == 0:
            num//=2
            
        else:
            num = 3*num + 1
        
        iterations += 1
        
    
    if iterations > highest:
        highest = iterations
        highest_num = i
        print(highest_num)
        
    return highest, highest_num
    

    
    
   
   

for i in range(1, 101, 1):
    result = Collatz(i, highest, highest_num)
    highest = result[0]
    highest_num = result[1]
```

P.S The answer is 97

Comment: A basic optimization might be to reuse previous results for numbers 1 to n-1 when trying number n, if you encounter one of this numbers in n's sequence. A more complicated one, using more memory, would be to cache the results for all numbers you encounter in each sequence.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Thanks for the help. Is there anyway to determine by looking at a number that it won't be long. I've looked for a trend in the longest numbers but I can't find one. They are as follows: 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 9, 18, 25, 27, 54, 73, 97, 129, 171, 231, 313, 327, 649, 703

Comment: A serious problem with this code is that it switches to floating point after encountering the first even number.  This is due to `num = num / 2`.  That will produce a floating point result.  Change it to `num = num // 2`, which will perform integer division and produce an interger result.  You can also shorten it to `num //= 2`.

Comment: Also, you can speed up the odd case by changing `num = 3*num + 1` to `num = (3*num + 1) // 2`, then incrementing `iterations` by `2` instead of `1`.  This works since `3*num + 1` will always be even, so there's no need to test it.

Comment: @Luca Krishnan just for curiosity... how do you call your function? in your code the initial values `high`, `high_num` are missing. Further, there is a _bug_ at `highest_num = i ` since `i` is not defined. Could you fix them, please?

Comment: This sounds more like a code review question than a SO question. You might want to take a look at [the codereview.stackexchange.com guidelines](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5777) to see if your question fits there instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can save result of previously computed numbers is some dict and then use it when you reach some of that numbers. Here is sample code:

```py
cache = {}
max_iter = 0
max_iter_num = 0

def collatz(num):
    global cache
    global max_iter
    global max_iter_num
    
    iterations = 0
    n = num
    numbers = []
    while n > 1:
        numbers.append(n)
        if n%2 == 0:
            n //= 2
        
        else:
            n = 3*n + 1
            
        iterations += 1
        
        if n in cache.keys():
            iterations += cache[n]
            break
        
    for i, n in enumerate(numbers):
        cache[n] = iterations - i
    
    if iterations > max_iter:
        max_iter = iterations
        max_iter_num = num
    

for i in range(1, 101):
    collatz(i)
```

Time comparision:

- code from question:

```
626 µs ± 8.08 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

- my code:

```
67.2 µs ± 1.48 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

Comment: is it normal that in the report message you have different amount of loops?

Comment: @cards yes. Usually the faster the script is the more times it is executed.